# Can preposition "to" means "with"?

Tags: headlinese

I came across that headline in NYtimes:

"Seahawks plan to trade Russell Wilson to the Broncos"

is it same as:

"Seahawks plan to trade Russell Wilson WITH the Broncos"???

Comment: Check your examples. They are identical. I suspect you meant to use the preposition **with** in the second.

Comment: In the context of trading a player to another sports team, *to* is idiomatic, not *with*.

Comment: @Ronald Sole, you're ritght, I've edited. tnks

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty, "tade to" is a phrasal verb?

Comment: @henrykearaudjo I don't think *trade to* is a phrasal verb, I just think *to* is the idiomatic preposition in that context. While the player may have been traded for another player, if only one player is mentioned and his destination is being described, the word *to* is used.

Comment: In addition to what @JackO'Flaherty said, sometimes we face some problems in other languages we learn due to incorrect translations. You might face a preposition in a language in a specific situation that you don't even use one in your own language. Or some other times when you translate a preposition and you don't change the translation in other situations with the same preposition, you face these kinds of issues you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Trading with** (a country or region) is basically about **commerce**. They conducted their trading with animal skins, not coins.

Also, you can trade places with someone at a table, or in a row of seats, for example.

If you exchange one player for another "with" does not work. However, "for" does work. They plan to trade player A **for** player B.

Also, you can *trade one player to another team*.